# Js extension modification not showing up in magento

Tags: javascript, https, magento-1.8

So I have installed an extension in magento for a popup. The extension worked fine but i wanted to change the size of the popup wich is calculated in a js (fancybox). When I finally made it to make the changes that I wanted I noticed that Magento is not serving me the new modified javascript file.

This is what I tried so far by googling all around:

- Refreshing the cache
- Flush the js/CSS cache
- Flush the store cache
- changing permissions on the file to 666 then back to 644
- changing the js merge on or off
- Checking the cache in the database (all clear)
- Checking if unsecure route and secure route are spelled fine (in the database and in magento admin panel, not very sure how this work though)

I am going mad.

One more thing:

If I access the js file from secure path

- https://mysite/jspath/jsfile.js (it shows the old file)

  And if:
- http://mysite/jspath/jsfile (it shows the new file)
- http://mysite//jspath/jsfile (it shows the new file)

Since I am not the only admin in the site I don't know if someone else made change to some magento configuration

Any idea is welcome and appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If compilation is on, re run the compilation process.

Due to the fact that it is serving up the old file still, it seems like there is still come caching there. You say you flushed the js/css cache. Can you flush all caches and see if its still a problem?

Comment: Compilation was never on and I already tried to flush all the cache, shall I run the compilation process anyway ?

Comment: @Byzs sorry I missed the part where you said you had flushed store cache. I don't think it is a compilation issue. It could be related to the Unsecured Base URL being set to something different to the Secured Base URL.

Comment: But even if that, since all cache are wiped why it keeps loading the old file ?

Comment: One more thing, unsecured and secured URL are fine in the core_config_data, btw thanks for the help

Comment: @Byzs I'm not sure what that would be happening to be honest. You've checked everything I can think of. Unless it is cached on your computer, but I don't think this is likely.

Can you check your magento file system? Because there may be cache's lying around. I don't think it's likely as you have cleared it out in the backend but it may pay to check manually clearing cache: https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_clear_the_cache_in_magento/